# Javascript rounding issue - trying with different methods with different results

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I know this question has been asked before and i've tried multiple solutions without success and seems more complex than it seems...

I'm working with product prices after a discount is applied so I will be rounding the numbers to 2 decimal places

So take this example code, would would expect each number to round up, except sometimes it rounds down...

```
let numbers = []
numbers.push(1.782); 
numbers.push(4.705);
numbers.push(4.715);
numbers.push(4.725);
numbers.push(4.735); 
numbers.push(4.745);
numbers.push(4.755);
numbers.push(4.765);
numbers.push(4.775);
numbers.push(4.785);
numbers.push(4.795);

for (let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
  console.log('TEST 1 - num#'+i+ ' ['+numbers[i]+'] toFixed = '+ (numbers[i]).toFixed(2) )
}

function roundToDecimal(num) {
  return Math.round(num * 100) / 100  
}

for (let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
  console.log('TEST 2 - num#'+i+ ' ['+numbers[i]+'] roundToDecimal = '+ roundToDecimal(numbers[i]) )
}
```

Which returns:

```
TEST 1 - num#0 [1.782] toFixed = 1.78
TEST 1 - num#1 [4.705] toFixed = 4.71 
TEST 1 - num#2 [4.715] toFixed = 4.71 // wrong
TEST 1 - num#3 [4.725] toFixed = 4.72 // wrong
TEST 1 - num#4 [4.735] toFixed = 4.74
TEST 1 - num#5 [4.745] toFixed = 4.75
TEST 1 - num#6 [4.755] toFixed = 4.75 // wrong
TEST 1 - num#7 [4.765] toFixed = 4.76 // wrong
TEST 1 - num#8 [4.775] toFixed = 4.78
TEST 1 - num#9 [4.785] toFixed = 4.79
TEST 1 - num#10 [4.795] toFixed = 4.79

TEST 2 num#0 [1.782] roundToDecimal = 1.78
TEST 2 num#1 [4.705] roundToDecimal = 4.71
TEST 2 num#2 [4.715] roundToDecimal = 4.72
TEST 2 num#3 [4.725] roundToDecimal = 4.72 // wrong
TEST 2 num#4 [4.735] roundToDecimal = 4.74
TEST 2 num#5 [4.745] roundToDecimal = 4.75
TEST 2 num#6 [4.755] roundToDecimal = 4.76
TEST 2 num#7 [4.765] roundToDecimal = 4.76 // wrong
TEST 2 num#8 [4.775] roundToDecimal = 4.78
TEST 2 num#9 [4.785] roundToDecimal = 4.79
TEST 2 num#10 [4.795] roundToDecimal = 4.8
```

I know about floating point notation issues... but this is so inconsistent i'm unsure how to proceed!

Has anyone got a workable solution?

Comment: There is no inconsistency; the reasons would be visible if you printed the full values of the numbers. It is simply that, when the decimal numerals are rounded to `Number` values, the rounding is sometimes upward and sometimes downward. 4.725 rounds to a number just below 4.725, and 4.715 rounds to a number just above 4.715, the same way ⅓ rounded to decimal rounds to a number just below ⅓ (.333) and ⅔ rounds to a number just above (.667). So your `numbers` array does not have 4.715 or 4.725 in it; it has `Numbers` values that have been rounded.

Comment: The multiplying by 100 for more rounding adds more complications. It is futile to attempt to work with decimal numbers using the binary-based `Number` format without expertise in floating-point. Depending on what you wanted to do, you could just keep scaled numbers, like 4715 instead of 4.715. But, to get a fuller solution, you need to explain what you want to do with these numbers. All you have shown is printing them, which is easy. What else do you need to do with the numbers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - thanks for the reply... I'm working with product prices after a discount is applied

Comment: Keep the prices in units of cents, or any smaller decimal unit you work with. Round them to a whole number of cents before printing. When printing, you can divide by 100 and print that to two decimal places. That will round to the desired decimal numeral for all reasonable dollar amounts (up to trillions of dollars). Note that rounding errors can still occur in other calculations, such as computing compound interest.

Comment: @EricPostpischil but isn't my roundToDecimal() doing what you suggest?

Comment: No, it is not. If you divide 1 by 100 in the `Number` type, the result is not .01. It is 0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375. You need to work in units of cents, so $.01 is represented as the number 1, because you cannot represent it as .01, just 0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375. You can round only just before printing, because the rounding error at that point will not matter, if done correctly.